# Object shows up in console but always adds an undefined or empty array at start

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to perform some logic on an object. When I print the object to the console `console.log(question);` I see the object as follows:

```
[15:23:06] undefined
[15:23:06] Object {
[15:23:06]   "id": "213a3e34-1a86-4ae5-bd7c-c882fd1684f8",
[15:23:06]   "text": "What is 4+4",
[15:23:06] }
```

However, I am having trouble actually referencing the values. When I try `question['text']` I get a type error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'question["text"]')

I see that there is an undefined being logged on the Console but cannot understand where there comes from.

As a note, my object is pulled from an array of objects as:

```
question = this.state.questions[1];
```

Where the questions are being pulled from the state.

When I log `this.state.questions` to the console, I dont see anything undefined, and rather, I see an empty array added at top:

```
[15:22:11] Array []
[15:22:11] Array [
[15:22:11]   Object {
[15:22:11]     "id": "407e7560-a0cd-4272-bafc-795f5e5787be",
[15:22:11]     "text": "What is 2+4",
[15:22:11]   },
[15:22:11]   Object {
[15:22:11]     "id": "213a3e34-1a86-4ae5-bd7c-c882fd1684f8",
[15:22:11]     "text": "What is 4+4",
[15:22:11]   },
[15:22:11]   Object {
[15:22:11]     "id": "9d38c759-6b64-4c1f-9e0e-d3b95a72b3a8",
[15:22:11]     "text": "What is 1+2",
[15:22:11]   },
[15:22:11] ]
```

This leads me to believe that

Comment: Need to see more code around your console expressions as well as where you are accessing it.

Comment: Check the index you use in this.state.questions. Are you sure you have the object you are referring to at index 1?

Comment: He is saying that he is able to console log it.

Comment: Added some more context. It seems that there is an undefined somewhere appearing but cannot understand where this is coming from as all is defined in the overall array.

Comment: If the data is not yet present in "this.state.questions[1]" then it will return as undefined even if "this.state.questions" is an empty array..

Comment: @Perniferous, thats probably exactly what it is. Even though the function that loads the state should wait till its loaded. Would you have a suggestion to handle this?

Comment: @Perniferous, I can confirm that your suggestion is spot on. If I add a short delay - works perfectly. Now I just need to find out how to force the load to wait for the state to be filled.

Comment: so it is not defined when it is initialized. Guessing you do it in an asynchronous manner.... Sounds like you need to check if it is loaded before accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information given, the property is accessed before the data is actually inside the state. Trying to access "this.state.questions[1]" will give undefined if the data has not been previously loaded in (even if "this.state.questions" is an empty array).

To avoid this, make sure any function that is utilizing this value is either: an async function chained onto whatever function is getting data, or use conditionals to ensure the value isn't undefined. For example:

```
if(typeof this.state.questions[1] !== "undefined") {
 //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, have chained on the async load